# Set default value with "IN" statment?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-in

How to set default value with "`IN`" statment, like this:

```
SELECT username
FROM user
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
ORDER BY FIELD(id,1,2,3,4)
```

If `id = 2` is not available then return `0` or `null`, like this:

```
John33
0
amanda1
erik
```

Comment: SELECT (CASE WHEN username IS NULL THEN 0 end) as username FROM

Comment: @Mihai - or use [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) ;)

Comment: @Mihai you should post an answer with coalesce... it'll get some votes :) I would have but your comment beat me :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell Meh just post the answer,the coast is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this with a `left join`:

```
SELECT u.username
FROM (select 1 as id union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
     ) ids left join
     user u
     on u.id = ids.id
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Logic in the `where` clause cannot "add" new rows to the result set.

Answer (score 2):

An `IN (list)` comparison returns a boolean, (TRUE, FALSE or NULL) for every row it's evaluated for.

So, a `foo IN (list)` cannot (by itself) "produce" a row that's not available in the row source.

(You say that `id = 2` "is not available", we take that to mean that there is no row in `user` that satisfies that predicate.)

You could produce the resultset as shown, but it doesn't require an `IN` comparison at all.

You need a rowsource that is guaranteed to return the "id" values you want; an inline view is a convenient way to do that.

```
SELECT u.username
  FROM ( SELECT 1 AS id
         UNION ALL SELECT 2
         UNION ALL SELECT 3
         UNION ALL SELECT 4
       ) n
  LEFT
  JOIN user u 
    ON u.id = n.id
 ORDER BY n.id
```

The LEFT JOIN specifies an outer join operation. That is, if there is no matching row from the table on the right side (`user`) that matches a row from the table on the left side (`n`), then the query will return the row from `n` along with `NULL` values for all the columns from `user`.

You can replace that NULL value for username replaced using an expression in the SELECT list. Check if `u.id` is NULL (which would mean there was no matching row found), and return something else. For example, the literal `0`.

```
SELECT IF(u.id IS NULL,'0',u.username) AS username
```

That's MySQL specific syntax for the ANSI-standard equivalent

```
SELECT CASE WHEN u.id IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE u.username END AS username
```

If you want to replace all NULL values of `username`, not just NULL values produced when a `user` row is missing:

```
SELECT IFNULL(u.username,'0') AS username
```